# Javascript encoded syntax?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding a unit converter to my website from this link: http://www.unitconversion.org/faq.html

And as I was looking at the code I ran across code that looked like this in the JS file:

```
\x00@4\f*0(_\b!\x00Y\x00Q1%\nB;\bTY)\x0b TDD m2&Nw\t&P(cHH;dlA,M\b,L<-A\bQ\b\n+|kL2\x00HGW
\ra-+\fA@7d%1H5\"\x00,@~fi\x00t 2Bc&8GeWE\x00j1\
```

It's javascript as its in the JS file but I've never seen syntax like that

From what I can tell, part of the code starts and ends when there `\` is shown.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: @Charlie — It appears to be designed to make it hard to decipher. Decoding it is likely trivial, but not worth the effort. (OTOH, including obfuscated code is risky and I'd look for another solution.

Comment: @Charlie -- Check this [link](http://www.stunnix.com/prod/jo/) for an animated example :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code [here](http://www.unitconversion.org/converter3/converter3.js) includes the encoded code, a decoding algorithm and an `eval` expression.

If you instead of `eval` simply log the decoded version of the code, you'll see it's just plain JavaScript.

Then if you make [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) indent things, it will become a little more readable. Still though, they've used inscrutable variable names, but nevertheless you can view the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Hhzy/).

Comment: @Charlie: Copy the source, and replace `eval` with `console.log` (at the very end). Then it will simply reveal the decoded version instead of execute it.

Comment: So I change the last part to `console.log(jx2_0(jx2_1));`? Doing that still shows the obfuscated code.

Comment: @Charlie: It still shows *unreadable* code but at least you now have correct JavaScript instead of mess like `0Y\x00Q1%\nB`. You can then copy that JavaScript into jsbeautifier.

Answer (score 1):

The code has been obfuscated, which means it has been voluntarily rendered unreadable for humans.

More general information on code obfuscation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

(Sorry for linking to Wikipedia.)